# Specify assembly location

Tags: wpf, deployment, app-config, xbap

Hi I have created WPF(XBAP) application.
In that for the referred assemblies Build Action is specified as Embedded Resource.
But still the .NET will look for the actual assemblies.
Is there any way to tell the .NET that assembly is embedded resource.

e.g. MyApp.dll is the XBAP which uses Comp.dll
I have added Comp.dll as item in MyApp project.
However In execution MyApp look for Comp.dll instead it should look in the resources.

Answer (score 0):

These links might answer your queries to `embed DLL's` as resource in your exe -

[Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)

[C#: How to embed DLL into resourcefile (no dll copy in program directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494366/c-how-to-embed-dll-into-resourcefile-no-dll-copy-in-program-directory)

[Merge .dll into C# Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356798/merge-dll-into-c-sharp-assembly/4382512#4382512)